# Hooke's law and the conservation of energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, spring, home-experiment

We did a Hooke's Law lab in class today in which we held a mass (100 g) under a hanging spring, and then let it drop. We were supposed to collect the displacement (18.7 cm) as data.  [Here is the link to the lab.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14Rd7N2p0MKylRZLwmEoTnEMtjP1hgKY4)  (Note that the first part of the lab was for determining the spring constant, and there is also an irrelevant section about series and parallel springs.)

We calculated that the spring constant was 62 N/m. Based on this, the potential spring energy would be $$E_e = \frac{1}{2}kx^2 = \frac{1}{2}(62.5)(0.187)^2 = 1.09  J$$

However, according to the law of conservation of energy, the potential spring energy at the bottom should be 0.183 J because the gravitational potential energy at the top is $E_g = ghm = 9.81 * 0.187 * 0.1 = 0.183 J$. (I'm measuring height from the bottom of the displacement).

What am I missing?
(If anyone would like to look at my data, it is  [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AcO5DrU6Lp35U7NV7tboS5EpfuQh1GM86dZvJNMsWCo/edit?usp=sharing) )

Edit: I see now that my data for the spring constant is very inconsistant. Thanks for the feedback!
Edit #2: I talked to my lab mates and realized that all the error was due to a typo: the mass was 500 g, not 100 g. Everything makes a lot of sense now :)

Comment: You should double check your results... just with the data here, it's not consistent.  Hint: Think about trial 2 of your spring constant data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to suggest high uncertainty in your spring constant. A possible error may be with your displacement.

You need to be careful what you use for your displacement in your spring potential energy equation. The displacement is how much the spring is stretched or compressed from its natural length (length of spring hanging with no mass on it).

You said the height it falls is 18.7 cm but you also said the displacement of the spring is 18.7 cm, which is only true if you released the mass from the springs natural length. 
If you didn't release the mass from the springs natural length then there is an initial displacement x and your initial energy of the mass would be:

$$E_{tot} = U_{spring} + U_{gravity}$$

Note, in the case of a hanging spring, the equilibrium position is not at the natural length of the spring.

Comment: Yes, I dropped it from the natural length, not from the equilibrium position. About the spring constant uncertainty; when I graphed Force (the mass' weight) vs. Displacement, it seemed to show that the constant was 62.5 N/m. What do you mean by high uncertainty?

Comment: High uncertainty in that your values range from 49 to 70. But if you did indeed drop it from the equilibrium position, then I'd say the most likely error is just with an inaccurate measurement or set of measurements. The physics looks right

Answer (score -1):

Not sure i understood you well , but i know the law of conservation :) . You should measure the distance to yhe ground when the spring is in equilibrium not attached to the mass , then you know when youll put a mass over there it will have a specific amount of energy that when youll drop it while its attached to spring , the energy will be converted to potential from the spring. Add up whats left and thats the total energy in the system

Comment: Thank you Yarin, that is in fact one way I solved for the potential energy. The problem is that when I try to solve it a different way, with the spring constant, I get a totally different number.